# Dastardly Diagrams

Tags: word, visual

I recently found this diagram taped over an image in my English textbook. We got it second-hand, so I assume that it must have been a little puzzle from the previous owner.
[image]

It came with two questions written under it on a separate piece of paper:

1. What word should replace the question mark?
2. Can you make a similar diagram with the words **direction, quench, bench** and **bristle**? (among other words)

Can you help me decode the diagram?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think we should

> replace the diagram with this one:
>
> ```
>      tops
>     /  ! \
> spot---+--stop
>     \  | /
>      pots
>     /  | \
> post opts PTOs
> ```

where

> PTOs might mean "personal-time-offs" (absences from work) or "please-turn-overs" (indications that the thing you're looking for is absent from this page but present overleaf), probably the former, and is starred because it's an abbreviation rather than a word.

So the question mark

> might be replaced with any synonym for "pots". "pans" (cooking vessels), "sinks" (sends a snooker/pool ball into a pocket), "weeds" (marijuana, though the pluralization is a bit iffy), etc.

The colours

> indicate what permutation of letters is being done. Blue means reversal, red means moving a letter from one end to the other, green means swapping two letters.

For the second part, we have

> direction EAST, quench SATE, bench SEAT, bristle SETA. We could add TEAS, EATS, ETAS, and TASE. Something like this, if I haven't missed any adjacencies in the graph:
>  [image]

If we don't mind a bit of obscurity we could add

> ATES to make a nice 3x3 grid. It would be better to rearrange the top row a little, but this will do:
>  [image]

Comment: (SteveV's answer was posted while I was writing mine. Of course I didn't look at it before posting. Having done so, I see that mine's a bit more complete so I'm leaving it here despite coming in second.)

Comment: as you should :)  i came back to add rot13(xrggyr) for the question mark but i think i'll leave mine as is

Comment: Wow, seems this puzzle took people a bit less time than expected. This is the correct answer for the first part, but for the second question you need a complete diagram (naq gurer ner zber nantenzf guna lbh unir abgrq urer)

Comment: OK, I'll add a diagram for the second one. I thought the principle was obvious at this point and filling in all the details was unnecessary, but apparently not :-).

Comment: Diagram added (with some more words, of course).

Comment: Good job on getting yourself the tick! Your diagram appears to be missing a few connections that I had noted but you've definitely done enough work to get yourself some applause!

Comment: I'm good at missing things :-). I had another look and noticed a kind of green connection that for some reason I've systematically failed to notice. Will update in a minute.

Comment: OK, missing links added. Maybe I have all of them now. The diagrams are less tidy with the extras, alas; I laid them out with my original incomplete sets in mind.

Answer (score 4):

I note that

> the words are synonyms of anagrams of each other

So that you get

> tops
>   spot  stop
>   pots
>   post opts ???

I don't know

> what absenses* means yet nor if the colors are significant

For the second part, direction, quench, bench and bristle

> have synonyms
>  east, sate, seat, seta  which are anagrams of each other